# Tkinter classes are confusing me (basic )

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, tk-toolkit, object-oriented-analysis

I am new to python and programming in general and I have been trying to make a simple GUI program using Tkinter but it does not run and I don't understand the errors I get?

the Errors are: GUI instance has no attribute 'frame'

Global name 'frame' is not defined.

MY code, I have removed some unncessary stuff.

```
class GUI:
   def __init__(self,master):

        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.master=master

        now=datetime.datetime.now()



        self.date=str(now.month)+':'+str(now.day)+':'+str(now.year)

        self.time1=str(now.hour)+':'+str(now.minute)+':'+str(now.second)

        temp=14
        humidity=15

        self.userinput=StringVar()

        self.password=StringVar()

        #self.geometry('250x250+200+200')

        #self.title('Controller GUI')

        date_label=Label(frame,text='Date : %s' %self.date)

        time_label=Label(frame,text='Time: %s' %self.time1)

        temp_label=Label(frame,text='Temperature: %d C'%temp)

        hum_label=Label(frame,text='Humidity: %d%%'%humidity)



        EnterMail=Label(frame,text='Enter Gmail username:')

        EnterPass=Label(frame,text='Enter password:')


        self.mail_box=Entry(frame,textvariable=self.userinput)

        self.pass_box=Entry(frame,textvariable=self.password)


        self.EnterButton=Button(frame,text='Enter',command=self.printer)

        self.StartAlarm=Button(frame,text='Start Alarm',command=self.startalarm)

        self.StopAlarm=Button(frame,text='Stop Alarm',command=self.stopalarm)

        date_label.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)

        time_label.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=E)

        temp_label.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

        hum_label.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=E)

        EnterMail.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W)

        EnterPass.grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.mail_box.grid(row=4,column=2)

        self.pass_box.grid(row=5,column=2)

        self.EnterButton.grid(row=7,column=0)

        self.StartAlarm.grid(row=8,column=0)

        self.StopAlarm.grid(row=10,column=0)

        mainloop()

    def startalarm(self):
        alarmlabel=Label(self.frame,text='Alarm Activated')
        alarmlabel.grid(row=11,column=0)
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
        return


    def stopalarm(self):
        alarmlabel=Label(frame,text='Alarm Deactivated')
        alarmlabel.grid(row=11,column=0)
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
        return


    def printer(self):  # prints user input
        self.username=self.userinput.get()
        self.MailPass=self.password.get()
        print username
        print MailPass
        mail = int(feedparser.parse("https://" + self.username + ":" +
        self.MailPass +"@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom")["feed"]["fullcount"])

        mail_label=Label(frame,text='Email: %d unread emails' %self.mail)
        mail_label.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

        return

        root=Tk()
      app=GUI(master=root)
```

the website messed up some of the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change every single `frame` in your functions to `self.frame`. It should fix the problem. This makes it an instance variable.

When you defined `frame` in `__init__`, you're only defining it on the scope of that function, and thus can't be used in the others.

If you refer it as an instance variable, `self.frame`, all of your functions will have the  same variable, passed from the `self` argument. Problem Solved!

Comment: thank you that fixed the problem but I don't understand why the GUI doesn't update itself?

Comment: That's a separate question :) I'm good with classes, unfortunately i'm not that good with tkinter. But if you feel this answer is helpful, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

well in the `__init__` you need to make `frame` a class variable by making it `self.frame` then it can be used anywhere in the class

its telling you `frame` isnt defined because its ony defined in the scope of the `__init__` instead of the whole class

more on [Classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

your last 3 lines should look like this:

```
root = Tk()
app = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you that fixed the problem but I don't understand why the GUI doesn't update itself?

Comment: @user3064033 look at my answer you need to use the mainloop on the root like i showed